# Sort by multiple dimensions in crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, crossfilter

I'm using Mike Bostock's [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter) library to filter and sort large datasets. My problem: **Given a dataset with multiple dimensions, how can I sort on more than one dimension at a time?**

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/cQXNK/)

Test dataset:

```
[
    { cat: "A", val:1 },
    { cat: "B", val:2 },
    { cat: "A", val:11 },
    { cat: "B", val:5 },
    { cat: "A", val:3 },
    { cat: "B", val:2 },
    { cat: "A", val:11 },
    { cat: "B", val:100 }
]
```

Example of desired output, sorting by `cat, val` (ascending):

```
[
    { cat: "A", val:1 },
    { cat: "A", val:3 },
    { cat: "A", val:11 },
    { cat: "A", val:11 },
    { cat: "B", val:2 },
    { cat: "B", val:2 },
    { cat: "B", val:5 },
    { cat: "B", val:100 }
]
```

The approach I've used thus far is to use string concatenation on the desired dimensions:

```
var combos = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.cat + '|' + d.val; });
```

This works fine with multiple string-based dimensions, but won't work with numeric dimensions, as it's not a natural sort (`'4' > '11'` ). I think I could make this work with zero-padding on the numbers, but this could get expensive for a large dataset, so I'd prefer to avoid it. **Is there another way that might work here, using crossfilter?**

Bonus points for any solution that allows different dimensions to have different sort directions (ascending/descending).

**Clarification**: Yes, I may need to switch to a native `Array.sort` implementation. But the whole point of using crossfilter is that it's very, very fast, especially for large datasets, and it caches sort order in a way that makes repeated sorts even faster. So I'm really looking for a crossfilter-based answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- I still use string concatenation on a single new dimension, but
- I convert the measure to a positive, comparable decimal before turning it into a string, using crossfilter to get the min/max:

  ```
  var vals = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.val }),
      min = vals.bottom(1)[0].val,
      offset =  min < 0 ? Math.abs(min) : 0,
      max = vals.top(1)[0].val + offset,
      valAccessor = function(d) {
          // offset ensures positive numbers, fraction ensures sort order
          return ((d.val + offset) / max).toFixed(8);
      },
      combos = cf.dimension(function(d) { 
          return d.cat + '|' + valAccessor(d); 
      });
  ```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/cQXNK/9/

This has the advantage of handling negative numbers properly - not possible with zero-padding, as far as I can tell. It seems to be just as fast. The downside is that it requires creating a new dimension on the numeric column, but in my case I usually require that in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not using the crossfilter library, but why not use the sort function to do this?

```
var combos = cf.sort(function(a,b) { 
   if(a.cat == b.cat) return a.val < b.val ? -1 : 1;
   return a.cat < b.cat ? -1 : 1;
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/cQXNK/5/

To allow different dimensions to have different sort directions would just be a matter of swapping -1 for 1 and vice versa

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, and I may need to switch to an `Array.sort` implementation. But the whole point of using crossfilter is that it's very, very fast, especially for large datasets, and it caches sort order in a way that makes repeated sorts even faster. So I'm really looking for a crossfilter-based answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Array.prototype.sort`, you can:

```
function sortByPriority(a, b) {
    var p = sortByPriority.properties;
    function pad (str, max) {
        str = String(str);
        return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }

    if (!p) {
        return a - b;
    }
    var ar ='', br = '';
    for (var i = 0, max = p.length; i < max; i++) {
        ar += pad(a[p[i]], 10);
        br += pad(b[p[i]], 10);
    }
    return ar == br ? 0 : ar > br ? 1 : - 1;
}
```

How to use:

Sorting `cat` then `val`

```
sortByPriority.properties = ['cat', 'val'];
myArray.sort(sortByPriority);
```

Result:

- A 1
- A 3
- A 11
- A 11
- B 2
- B 2
- B 5
- B 100

if you want prior `val` do:

```
sortByPriority.properties = ['val', 'cat'];
myArray.sort(sortByPriority);
```

Result:

- A 1
- B 2
- B 2
- A 3
- B 5
- A 11
- A 11
- B 100

Not a super effective code but, you can improve it.

**UPDATE:**

You can use the `pad` function to get same results using crossfilter, look [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gartz/cQXNK/6/).

```
var combos = cf.dimension(function(d) { 
    return pad(d.cat, 10) + '|' + pad(d.val, 10); 
});
```

You also can change the pad size by the same length from the biggest string in your "coll", this will ensure the result ever.

See that optimization: http://jsfiddle.net/gartz/cQXNK/7/

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, and I may need to switch to an `Array.sort` implementation. But the whole point of using crossfilter is that it's very, very fast, especially for large datasets, and it caches sort order in a way that makes repeated sorts even faster. So I'm really looking for a crossfilter-based answer here.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I read the crossfilter source, and they don't have a way to extend the sorting comparable function, they are all hard coded. You will need to extend the project and change it to give support you need. And for "large data" I would recomend web-sql or IndexedDB. They can ensure good results and are UI Thread free, for not freezing your UI.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I read your code again and it gave me an idea, so I have updated my answer to help you, and I think you will like :)

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the direction I'm going (though see the note in my question about performance concerns). Thanks!

Comment: @nrabinowitz If you don't want to padding, you will need to sort by `cat` then group the cat's objects that have same value, so do a sort in their `val` when finish re-join in a sorted result, that way you don't need to pad, but I don't think will be faster, you need to create a jsperf.com test to ensure that. To finish, you can do all the jobs using `web-workers`, and if you want go deeper, you can implement the algorithms using pre-fork with workers to get even fast. And won't freeze your UI. But is a hole new project. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested for preformance but you could give d3.nest a go. Example code:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.cat; })
.sortKeys(d3.ascending)
.sortValues(compareValues)
.entries(data);
```

See the whole fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/bZX7Q/

And let me know what result you get if you run some jsperf :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `d3.nest` is generally really slow compared to other options, especially crossfilter - it's mostly for data structure manipulation, not for fast processing.